# Navicat SQL import goes over the 100% limit

Tags: mysql, navicat

Today I imported a sql file of ~5GB to a new database using Navicat. It worked fine until I noticed that it is going more than the 100% level, and now its at 135%. Apparently there is no error shown.

But the import is still not completed. Any ideas whats wrong with this? Or is it normal to see this behavior? Do I need to wait until it finish?

This is the first time I'm importing a sql file using navicat. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks!![image]

Comment: I am encountering the same issue. Have a sql file which is 21GB. Importing it currently and the process is at 219%.

Answer (score 0):

Try use command line:
    mysql -D dbName -uUser -pPass < example.sql